# Saved JPEG is twice as large as the one loaded from disk after rotation

Tags: android

In my application I'm using the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent to get a picture taken. When the camera returns, the file is checked and if the rotation is portrait a the bitmap is rotated and saved out to disk with the following code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), options);
if (bmp != null) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), m,
                                        true);
    rotated = rotated.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false); // added based on comment
    f.delete();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    rotated.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

This works as it should, but the file size is twice that of non-rotated picture. I've tried setting the densities on the `BitmapFactory.Options` to 0 and the scale to false, but neither is having the desired effect. I want the image I transform to be the same size as the image I load from disk. Is there something in my code that is preventing this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original JPEG uses RGB565, which uses 2 bytes per pixel. Your in-memory bitmap derived from this file uses the "normal" format with 4 bytes per pixel; when this is saved to a new JPEG, it's saved with the denser format and thus is twice the size (this has nothing to do with its being rotated).

Comment: Pretty good description of how the size is calculated ;) Have actually been missing that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've added a line of code that should convert the rotated bitmap into the proper pixel format, but the issue persists. Any other thoughts? I thought that the pixel format had been considered in setting RGB_565 on the BitmapFactory.Options

Comment: I'm not sure how Android deals with bitmap formats like this. The line you changed probably has no effect on how the bitmap is outputted (re-compressed) to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're not allowing any lossy compression when converting to JPEG. Try setting your quality to 90 or 80, that should reduce the file size significantly.

And don't be frightened by the term "lossy". This is an essential part of JPEG which is why it gets the compression level that it does, but the loss is not so visible to the human eye.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a JPEG image without actually decoding and re-compressing it's pixels using [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html). Example:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
int old_orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
int new_orientation = ...; // implement your business logic here
exif.setAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION, new_orientation);
exif.saveAttributes();
```